# Value of a and b in the program given below

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

```
int main()
{
int a,b=3;
a=(b++)*(b++)*(b++);
printf("%d %d",a,b);
}
```

`a` becomes 27 but `b` is 6 after the execution of the expression.  Can anyone tell me how the
expression is executed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc), [Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: No one can tell you because it's undefined behavior. Please search SO for the many many other similar questions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Unfortunately for you, this question is a minor variant on a very commonly asked question — which is why your question will be closed.  You will find quite a lot of similar questions which are also closed as duplicates.

Comment: From a mathematical perspective, it would seem that the `b++` increments are not carried out until after the line `a=(b++)*(b++)*(b++);` is executed. All three increments are then carried out simultaneously hence why `b=6` when the next line is executed.

Comment: Given your results, it has been evaluated *on this occasion* as `a = b * b * b; b += 3;`. In other words the compiler has placed all of the modifications of `b` at the end of the statement, after `a` has been calculated. You could perhaps examine a disassembly to confirm this, and play around with optimization options to see if you can provoke some other result. If that seems an incorrect result to you, well, that's what you get for writing code with undefined behavior, the compiler wastes your time trying to work out what's going on ;-)

Comment: @steve Am I right in thinking that the answer won't always evaluate in this way then when recompiled?

Comment: @Ren: The standard says that behavior is undefined, which means it's not even guaranteed to always evaluate this way each time you run the same executable, let alone recompiling it. In practice, you'll probably see that the same compiler with the same options will produce a consistent result, and some compilers will produce a consistent result for certain statements like this regardless of options. You're just not allowed to rely on that.

Comment: if a=(++b)*(++b)*(++b) then output is  a=150 b=6

Comment: @user1619903: so in that case it appears to have computed 5*5*6 -- of the three reads of `b`, two of them were after two of the increments, and the other one was after all three. Got to love that crazy undefined behavior.